# Access Form Paints Too Late

Tags: ms-access, vba

With necessary preliminary tasks in the OnLoad event of my MainForm (via slow-ish called functions: server checks, data retrieval, etc.), the MainForm seems to insist upon painting only upon the conclusion of these preliminary tasks.  The result is several seconds of BLANK screen, with no indication anything is happening.

I have provided status messages at each step to a text box on the MainForm (followed by DoEvents), but due to the late painting of the MainForm, they nevery actually appear.  However, my code is aware of the controls and their values even though I cannot see them yet.

I have tried sprinkling in Me.Refesh along the way without result.

Any suggestions to paint the form earlier/first, then run those functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move some or all of these calls to a later event:

- OnCurrent
- OnActivate

Or create a *splash screen* that loads these things, then open your main form.

Set your main form to close the splash screen.

Comment: Thanks @Gustav.  OnActivate seems a good approach.  However, I notice that event seems to fire TWICE on my MainForm.  Any thoughts why this might be?

Comment: That will only happen if the form gets deactivated and then activated again.

Comment: Hmmm, you are right.  I can see the form Deactivate, then re-Activate.  I'll call this question SOLVED, and move onto determining WHY the form is Deactivated (not intentional).